# Plotly Hover breaks when adding color attribute

Tags: colors, hover, plotly-python

My graph is doing something strange. The hover data works for some of the points, but not all of them.
When I comment out the color piece, it works just fine. But I really would like the colors to stay.

Here is my code for the graph:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(data['df'])
    df['MeasureDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['MeasureDate'], infer_datetime_format=True)
    df['Sign'] = np.where(df['DeviationValue'] > 0, 'Positive', 'Negative')
    fig = px.area(df, 
                  y='DeviationValue', 
                  title=f"Graph of {data['engine']} going back one year from {data['date']}",
                  color='Sign',
                  color_discrete_map={
                    'Positive': 'green',
                    'Negative': 'red'
                  },
                  labels={
                    "DeviationValue": 'Deviation',
                    'index': ''
                  },
                  custom_data=['MeasureDate', 'DeviationValue']
                )
    fig.update_traces(showlegend=False, hovertemplate='Date: %{customdata[0]} <br>Deviation: %{customdata[1]}')
```

Please let me know if you have any solutions or thoughts! Thanks!